# Querying arrays into arrays on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have a collection with this pattern:

```
{
 "_id" : dfaje93r434,
 "number": 134500,
 "name": [ 'JOHN', 'SMITH', 'BYRNE' ]
}
```

I'd like to perform a query in which a random user introduces a list, and elements of this list are matched inside the  collection array.
Here's an example:

```
db.collection.find({ "name": [ 'JOHN', 'BYRNE'] })
```

In this case, the query should check the collection and, if the two elements match two elements inside a name, return true.

What is an efficient way to go?

My question has not been asked here. The case they point out has to do with a larger array being searched in another one.

Comment: It's not the same case. In my case, I'm looking for a array in another larger one.

Comment: It's the same all you need do is exchange the position of the `$setIsSubset` expressions like this.....: `{ "$setIsSubset": [[ 'JOHN', 'BYRNE'], "$name"] }`. That is why it's *Possible duplicate*